# Issue with using custom JSR303 annotation to validate method parameter in Spring mvc container

Tags: spring, configuration, spring-mvc, annotations, bean-validation

I build a simple application using Spring, and I try to implement a custom `JSR303` annotation to validate method string parameter. I use Java code to config Spring container and I think that I have loaded all the spring beans that I need. But the validation annotation still doesn't work.

Here is the code:

**Configure Spring:**

```
@Configuration

@Lazy(false)

public class MVCContainerConfig 
{
    @Bean
    public AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter annotationMethodHandlerAdapter()
    {
        ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer configurableWebBindingInitializer = new ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer();
        configurableWebBindingInitializer.setValidator(localValidatorFactoryBean());

        AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter annotationMethodHandlerAdapter = new AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter();
        annotationMethodHandlerAdapter.setWebBindingInitializer(configurableWebBindingInitializer);
        annotationMethodHandlerAdapter.setMessageConverters(new HttpMessageConverter[]{
            new BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter(), 
            new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter(),
            new FormHttpMessageConverter(), 
            new ResourceHttpMessageConverter(), 
            new StringHttpMessageConverter(),
            new AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter(),
            new RssChannelHttpMessageConverter(),
            new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter(),
            new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter(), 
            new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter(),
            new XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter()
        });

        return annotationMethodHandlerAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping defaultAnnotationHandlerMapping()
    {
        DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping defaultAnnotationHandlerMapping = new DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping();
        defaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.setInterceptors(new Object[]{localeChangeInterceptor(),
                                                                     themeChangeInterceptor()});
        return defaultAnnotationHandlerMapping;
    }

    @Bean(name="validator")
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean()
    {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();

        return localValidatorFactoryBean;
    }
... (ignore useless code)
}
```

**Annotation definition:**

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy={NotEmptyOrWhitespaceValidatorImp.class})
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@ReportAsSingleViolation
@NotNull
public @interface NotEmptyOrWhitespace 
{
    //TODO change this when language package is ready
    public abstract String message() default "Empty or white space error message";

    public abstract Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    public abstract Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

    /**
     * Defines several {@code @NotEmptyOrWhitespace} annotations on the same element.
     */
    @Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    public @interface List {
        NotEmptyOrWhitespace[] value();
    }
}
```

**Constraint definition:**

```
public class NotEmptyOrWhitespaceValidatorImp implements ConstraintValidator<NotEmptyOrWhitespace, String>
{
    public void initialize(NotEmptyOrWhitespace annotation){}

    public boolean isValid(String str, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) 
    {
        str = str.replaceAll(" ", "");
        return ((str == null || str.isEmpty()) ? false : true);
    }
}
```

**The method I want to test:**

```
public boolean isOurProduct(@NotEmptyOrWhitespace String productName) 
    {
        productName = productName.trim().toLowerCase();
        return this.productSet.contains(productName);
    }
```

**Junit Test method:**

```
  @Test
        public void testIsOurProduct()
        {
            // If the annotation works, then I should see an exception occurred instead of the output
            System.out.println("********* "+this.finder.isOurProduct("  "));
        }
```

Comment: Your `MVCContainerConfig` class won't even compile. Please give us example code that compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Method Parameter Validation with JSR-303](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424858/method-parameter-validation-with-jsr-303). You need to trigger validation using AOP on method invocation.